# PHP CURL - how to tell if the entire file requested was not fully downloaded

Tags: php, curl, simplexml, proxies

I'm using CURL and a proxy to grab some xml files, occasionally only part of the XML document comes through and fails when I try to load/use the xml (simplexml_load_string).

I thought something like..

```
    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        // handle error
    }
```

would catch this sorta error via CURL errno..

> CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE (18)
>
> A file transfer was shorter or larger
>   than expected. This happens when the
>   server first reports an expected
>   transfer size, and then delivers data
>   that doesn't match the previously
>   given size.

However, this does not work, I think it might be due to using a proxy. Anything else I can check? My only thought now is to do a preg_match for the last bit of the XML document, but that seems less than ideal as I'm getting multiple types of XML documents and I'd have to write checks for each type.

Comment: As a note that has nothing to do with your question, you can shorten your code like this `if($error = curl_error($ch)){ ... }`.

Comment: I usually do that sorta thing, but that particular piece of code is copied directly from the php docs for curl_errno so you'll have to work your OCD on them :]

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same problem with a proxy and I fell short of solving the issue using cURL's error handlers. If you have access to both scripts (the one requesting and the one delivering the XML) have the requesting one deliver a unique code which it expects at the end of the XML:

```
// Request
http://localhost/getxml.php?id=4&uniq=1337
```

And append a comment at the end of the output:

```
<?xml encoding="..." ..?>
...
<!--1337-->
```

Comment: I do not have access to the one delivering the scripts unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Well, having an error already tells you that the XML file you got is invalid. What you need to do is catch that error and handle it.

One quick fix is this:

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
if($xml === false){ /* The XML was not valid. */ }
```

One log fix is this one:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
if( ($err = libxml_get_last_error()) !== false ){ /* We got ourselves an XML error. */ }
```

Comment: I am hoping to keep my checks on the data validity together in one place as I'm rerunning the curl request when it fails. By the time I get to the XML parsing bit it's past a 'point of no return', and I would have to run a group of XML grabs again (3 at a time using multi curl) which is less than ideal. I may have to load the xml string right after I grab it .. instead of later in my 'xmlManager' class.. which would do as you say, but would not maintain my segmentation of code that grabs the XML docs, and code that parses them.

Comment: Well... You could try to load immediately after you do the curl request just to see if it was a valid XML. Or, if this is too much of an overhead, you could look for the root tag (with a simple regex) and see if it closes.

Comment: Hadn't thought about loading it just to check.. I'm more constrained by the time it takes for the proxies to come in so I don't think I'll lose much by having to load them twice.. most are not to big anyway.